# Why got error using pagination in view file?

Tags: codeigniter-4

On codeigniter  4.3.7 site reading https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html?highlight=pagination#loading-the-library docs
I make pagination with code in control :

```
$data = [
    'categories' => $model->paginate($perPage),
    'pager' => $model->pager,
];

return view('admin/category/index', $data);
```

but in view file I got error :

```
Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Pager\Pager::hasPrevious()
```

on first referencing of $pager var. When I debug $pager var with code :

```
<?php echo '<pre>::$pager::'.print_r($pager,true).'</pre>';  ?>
```

I see that $pager is valid Pager class : https://prnt.sc/GwF5u3hdqAET

What is wrong in my code ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What output is in your view?

Comment: I got run time error Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Pager\Pager::hasPrevious()

Comment: As in - can you show us your View file ?

Answer (score 0):

The `hasPrevious` method exists on the `PageRenderer` (`CodeIgniter\Pager\PagerRenderer`) rather than the `Pager` (`CodeIgniter\Pager\Pager`) - which is why you're getting the error.

How are you displaying the links of the pager?

```php
$pager->links();
$pager->simpleLinks();
$pager->makeLinks();
```

Are you passing any paramaters to any of the above methods?

As [Antony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3897214/antony) has mentioned, without seeing the code in your view, it's difficult to answer.